# C Error: designator in initializer for scalar type 'item_vtable *'

Tags: c, interface, vtable

I'm trying to implement a set in C with virtual functions, using a virtual function table, and I'm having issues initializing the virtual function tables due to an error:

```
error: designator in initializer for scalar type 'set *' (aka 'struct _set *')
```

I was given (it's for an assignment) a generic 'set.c' and 'set.h' file as an interface, and so I suspect that I may not be approaching the idea of implementing it correctly.

Here is the relevant part of the set header:

```
typedef struct _set{
  const struct _set_vtable *vtable;
  const item_vtable *i_vtable;
  int size;
} set;

typedef bool (*SET_ADD_FXN)(set *, const void *);
typedef bool (*SET_CONTAINS_FXN)(const set *, const void *);
typedef void (*SET_PRINT_FXN)(const set *);
typedef void (*SET_DESTROY_FXN)(set *);

typedef struct _set_vtable
{
  SET_ADD_FXN add;
  SET_CONTAINS_FXN contains;
  SET_PRINT_FXN print;
  SET_DESTROY_FXN destroy;
} set_vtable;

bool set_add(set *s, const void *item);
bool set_contains(const set *s, const void *item);
void set_print(const set *s);
void set_destroy(set *s);
int set_size(const set *s);
```

The set.c file just forwards function calls through the set's function table to the function pointed to:

```
bool set_add(set *s, const void *item)
{
  return s->vtable->add(s, item);
}
...
```

And so, this is my attempt to implement a 'set231' that is a set with specific functionality:

```
//set231.h
#include "set.h"

typedef struct{
  set * const interface;
  const char **items;
} set231;

set231 *set231_create();
int set231_size(set231 *);

bool set231_add(set231 *, const void *);
bool set231_contains(const set231 *, const void *);
void set231_print(const set231 *);
void set231_destroy(set231 *);

extern set_vtable set231_vtable;
extern item_vtable set231_ivtable;

//set231.c
#include "set231.h"

const int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 4;
const int STRING_LENGTH = 16;

set231 *set231_create(){
set231 *new = {
  .interface = &((set *){
    .vtable = &set231_vtable,
    .i_vtable = &((item_vtable *){
      .compare = strcmpv,
      .destroy = free,
      .print = str_print,
      .clone = strdupe
    }),
    .size = 0
  }),
  .items = (void *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * INITIAL_CAPACITY)
};
  return new;
}

int set231_size(set231 *s){...}

bool set231_add(set231 *s, const void *item){...}
bool set231_contains(const set231 *s, const void *item){...}
void set231_print(const set231 *s){...}
void set231_destroy(set231 *s){...}

set_vtable set231_vtable = 
{
  .add = set231_add,
  .contains = set231_contains,
  .print = set231_print,
  .destroy = set231_destroy
};
item_vtable set231_ivtable =
{
  .compare = strcmpv,
  .destroy = free,
  .print = str_print,
  .clone = strdupe
};
```

When compiled, I get the designator in initializer error, as well as warnings for giving the set interface's virtual table functions that ask specifically for a set231 rather than a set.

```
warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'SET_ADD_FXN' (aka 'bool (*)(set *, const void *)') with an expression of type 'bool (set231 *, const void *)'
```

Comment: `.i_vtable = &((item_vtable *){` `.interface = &((set *){` << remove `*` here

Comment: but compound literal has automatic storage duration when declared in a block scope so your code won't work even if it compiles.

Comment: The line `.vtable = &set231_vtable,` doesn't compile itself, that's what's giving the designator in initializer error, so I guess I was looking for an alternative, how to initialize the set231 to point its internal set at a virtual table with set231 functions.

Comment: Don't cast he result of a call to `malloc()`. Doing so will hide the failure to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: In set231_create you're returning a pointer to stack allocated memory, causing undefined behavior.